# Why is lazy indexing Mode deleting my data in cosmos even if Time to Live(Ttl) is off?

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I used Lazy indexing mode to process for a smaller file, it worked fine. The reason i opted for Lazy indexing mode instead of Consistent indexing mode was that it consumed fewer RU's. But if I am trying to process a bigger file(more MB) with more number of events/rows, once the data gets inserted completely, then it starts deleting the inserted data. The only change i made to the default indexing policy in DB is changing the Indexing Mode from 'consistent' to 'Lazy' (TTL is still off).

> why is the data getting deleted through Lazy Indexing in cosmosdb-gremlin API?

```
{
    "indexingMode": "lazy",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "indexes": []
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ],
    "spatialIndexes": [
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "types": ["Point"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: indexing modes have nothing to do with TTL

Comment: Unique indexes dropping duplicates?